# How to return to terminal execution after running node fileName.js command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, command-line

I have a shell script as :

```
node fileName.js
echo "done";
exit 0;
```

my fileName.js :

```
console.log("script executed");
```

Now after running `node fileName.js` command, the terminal is not executing commands after it i.e `echo "done"; exit 0;`

So How can I return the control to terminal after executing node js file.

Comment: node fileName.js doesn't run your shell script at all.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine:

a.js :

```
console.log("from node")
```

a.sh :

```
#/bin/bash

node a.js
echo "from bash";
exit 0;
```

output : 
    bash a.sh

```
 from node
 from bash
```

You can try to add a process.exit(0) at the end of your node filename